# Intersecting dates postgres on joined tables maximum dates complex query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables which each have a start and end date.

```
e.g. 
Table 1
start_date | end_date | valueToJoin1 | ValueToJoin2 | fruit
 2000-01-01  2000-02-01    XXXX           YYYY       apple
 2000-01-01  2000-02-01    XXXX           BBBB       apple

Table 2
start_date | end_date | valueToJoin1 | ValueToJoin2 | vegetable
2000-01-15    2000-12-31    XXXX          YYYY        tomato

Table 3
start_date | end_date | car 
2000-01-05    2000-10-31   porsche
2000-02-02    2000-10-31   mazda
```

I want a query that lists rows for the intersecting tables based on the maximum possible start date where they overlap and the minimum possible end date where they overlap.  I also need the start and end dates for the 3rd table.

The tables need to be joined by certain values e.g. XXXX must match on both tables.

I also do not want any duplicates or unnecessary info.  Output for the above should be only one row:

```
 max_start_date | max_end_date | table_3_start_date | table_3_end_date |  joinedValue1 | joinedValue2 | vegetable | fruit | car
  2000-01-15       2000-02-01        2000-01-05         2000-10-31      XXXX          YYYY        tomato    apple   porsche
```

Comment: Are the tables joined by both columns named `valuetojoin`? Or is that only one column? If those are two columns it would be better if you used proper names rather than obfuscating them beyond usability. And how is table 3 joined to the other tables? And should the start/end date be part of the join? Can you supply a simply test setup with `create table` and `insert` statements?

Comment: Yes both.  I have updated the question

Comment: What about table3? How should that be joined to the other tables?

Comment: only by the overlapping date ranges...

Comment: And the others **only** by the join columns or by the join columns **and** the overlapping date ranges?

Comment: by the join columns and the dates

Comment: Have just added some more data to clarify it a bit more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this is what you want - at least it gives the output you want, based on your sample data:

```
select greatest(tb1.start_date, tb2.start_date, tb3.start_date) as max_start_date,  
       least(tb1.end_date, tb2.end_date, tb3.end_date) as max_end_date, 
       tb3.start_date as tb3_start_date, 
       tb3.end_date as tb3_end_date,
       tb1.j1, 
       tb1.j2,
       tb1.fruit,
       tb2.vegetable,
       tb3.car
from tb1 
  join tb2 
    on (tb2.j1, tb2.j2) = (tb1.j1, tb1.j2) 
   and daterange(tb2.start_date, tb2.end_date, '[]') && daterange(tb1.start_date, tb1.end_date, '[]')
  join tb3 
    on daterange(tb3.start_date, tb3.end_date, '[]') && daterange(tb1.start_date, tb1.end_date, '[]')
   and daterange(tb3.start_date, tb3.end_date, '[]') && daterange(tb2.start_date, tb2.end_date, '[]');
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/HBFY75494